# Override the SP CSS master page with !important

Tags: css, style.css

I'm building a menu on a SharePoint site page and I'm having difficulties with the CSS. Everything works well outside of SharePoint, but for some reason I'm not able to override the `box-shadow` and the font `color`.

I tried using the `!important` in my CSS rules. I tried using `!important` in CSS inline-style

```
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 220px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: -4.7em;
    margin-top: 0.89em;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 11px #dadada !important;
}
```

inline : `<div class = "dropdown-content" style = "box-shadow: 5px 5px 11px #dadada !important;">`

here is my code for the text in the menu

```
<li class = "li-drop" style="color:#000000# !important;"><a href="url" onclick="return go(this);">Text</a></li>
```

for some reason, the `box-shadow` and the font color in the `<a>` refuse to follow.

Anyone can help me figure this out?

Comment: are you need to reflect your style to <a> tag specifically for Text ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `!important`.  Have you tried adding selectors to increase the specificity of your styles?  Also, have you investigated what selectors SharePoint is using that causes your styles to be ignored?  You might be able to use exactly those to create a rule that has more specificity and thus override the SharePoint style.

Comment: yes, the <a> tag needs to show as text in the menu.

Comment: HI Dylan, I tried using selectors to increase the specificity but it's still ignoring it.

Comment: I finally figured the issue. Our version of SP doesn't support CSS3. Therefore, `box-shadow` will not work.

The font color for `<a>` is already forced with a `!important` in the master CSS change and can't be changed for business reasons. 

I will create a box shadow effect by overlapping 2 `<div>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution even though the font color for `<a>` is forced with a `!important` in the master CSS.

I used a `<div>` inside the `<a>` and switched the clicking zone on the entire `<li>` zone instead of the text within the `<li>`

This is what it looks like.

```
<li class = "li-drop"><a href="url" onclick="return go(this);"><div class = "div-drop">Text</div></a></li>
```